# Protecting unpublished or under review papers from theft

Tags: journals, peer-review

Would you please guide me how can I protect my under review or under revision papers from theft. It is possible that my papers have been stolen and they will be submitted to another journal. maybe a person want to disturb me and submit my papers as I have submitted them. Is it possible to save my papers in a site that demonstrate they are my own papers and I haven't submitted them to another journal simultaneously?

Comment: You can consider publishing a pre-print in for example https://arxiv.org/

Comment: Also see [What to do if I'm afraid that my idea will get stolen during review process?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/75028/11365), [Prevent plagiarism after rejection of a paper?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/36879/11365), [How can I “time-stamp” my data without publishing it?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/23367/11365)